# ESS in Yosemite

Tags: osx, ess

As already written elsewhere I have huge problems with my Emacs-Distribution after updating to Yosemite. The ESS-Version from Vincent Goulet (http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/) worked pretty well under Mavericks - though I had to restart it sometimes when it hang during the startup - but now I cannot start Emacs at all. What should I do to have a proper running Emacs (or better yet: ESS) under Yosemite?

Comment: Try installing `emacs` via macports. And installing ESS via ELPA/MELPA.

Answer (score 1):

Install Emacs via macports, and then install ESS inside `M-x list-packages` from [MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/ess).